# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling O236.writeDataset when tried to build a dataset

Tags: python, pyspark

I have one dataset that is building based on some conditions ( updates on inputs). This dataset fail sometimes and sometimes the build is done correctly. The message error I have is not So clear without any presicion.
The error message : py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling O236.writeDataset : Java.lang.StackoverflowError

Can you help me please with this issue. Thank you

Build sometimes good sometimes no

Comment: Please share the full traceback and line of error.

Comment: Also, please share your code and on what type of data you're working (schema etc.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.